# Create customer on laravel registration

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-authentication

All I want to do is to create a stripe customer account for every registered user on Laravel. 
The problem I'm facing right now is that `$new` variable isn't passing to `User::create` function.

I'm trying to edit RegisterController.php, here is create() function I'm using:

```
public function create(array $data)
{
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');

    $new = \Stripe\Customer::create([
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'description' => "Contribee.com platform's user",
    ]);

    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'stripe_code' => $new->id,
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

I've tested this out in my other controller, and `$new` outputs generated ID. Everything worked fine.

Comment: Is `stripe_code` in `User.php`'s array of `$fillable` fields?

Comment: @ceejayoz Thank you! Everything is working now :)

Comment: Awesome, I'll add that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#mass-assignment

> You may also use the `create` method to save a new model in a single line. The inserted model instance will be returned to you from the method. However, before doing so, you will need to specify either a `fillable` or `guarded` attribute on the model, as all Eloquent models protect against mass-assignment by default.

Anything not permitted as fillable gets discarded.